# Maximize and Minimize Buttons Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Using Visual Studio I created a app.manifest file in order to have the program be ran with Administrator permissions. I also edited this portion of the app.manifest file thinking it would be helpful:

```
 <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

After I ran the program I noticed that I was missing my Minimize, Maximize, and Expand buttons. So I went back and commented out that portion of code in app.manifest to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to rectify this issue?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9euo.png)

Tried commenting out the portion of code in the app.manifest

Comment: Set the form's ControlBox property back to True.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

**This is what happens when I set the Form's ControlBox property to false**

[image]

**This is what happens when I set the Form's ControlBox property to true**

[image]

[image]